# How to get a cakephp 3 application running in a shared hosting

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting

I'm developing a cakephp application, I did the first steps, bake, authentication and etc... the application is running in my machine, localhost with WAMP.

Then I uploaded to the shared hosting (Hostgator), before I upload the application I was reading many articles and tutorials about it, and there were several ways to do that, I followed the hosting company tutorial at this link: see first comment, but I'm getting an error:

> Authentication adapter "form" was not found.

You can see the page at http://bd.anje.org.mz/[2](http://bd.anje.org.mz/), but some files described don't exist, even in local installation, anyone ever had this error?

Comment: http://forum.hostgator.com.br/topic/1275-cakephp-3/

Comment: Maybe a route you've declared with ' \ ' in your windows is causing problems at your linux hosting. Try always to use `DS` instead of ' / ' or ' \ '.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the answer below solve the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a *case **in**sensitive* filesystem where the case of files you request doesn't really matter. If you have a file called `Test.php` and request it as `test.php` windows will hapilly serve it, same as `TeST.php` or any other combination of capital and low case letters.

Linux on the other hand uses a more sane *case sensitive* filesystem. If you ask for `test.php` when `Test.php` is available linux will say it didn't find `test.php` because that's what you literally asked for.

This means that if your mistype `form` instead of `Form` as an authentication object in the initialization of `AuthComponent`, cake will request a file called `formAuthenticate.php` from the filesystem (notice the low case `f`). Windows will produce the actual `FormAuthenticate.php` instead, inhibiting your mistake until you hit a (linux) production system like your hosting provider, that won't be able to find `formAuthenticate.php`.

So simply change the way you load the component to:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => ['Form'] //make sure this isn't 'form'
]);
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works now, the error was because 'form' instead of 'Form', thanks for the clear explanation.